# ubuntu: how to install private repository with composer using sudo

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, composer-php

We use for our symfony project beside the public sources also a private repository on our own gitlab server which is accessible via ssh.

If I clone only this private repository to my local ubuntu machine everything is fine.
If I use

```
$ sudo composer install
```

in the project which includes this repository I get following error message:

```
[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@gitlab.con.example.com:myprivaterepo.git' '/home/aliebermann/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.con.example.com-myprivaterepo.git/'
Cloning into bare repository '/home/myuser/.composer/cache/vcs/git-gitlab.con.example.com-myprivaterepo.git'...
    __________________________________________________________________
    |                                                                  |
    |  This system is for the use of authorized users only.  Usage of  |
    |  this system may be monitored and recorded by system personnel.  |
    |                                                                  |
    |  Anyone using this system expressly consents to such monitoring  |
    |  and is advised that if such monitoring reveals possible         |
    |  evidence of criminal activity, system personnel may provide the |
    |  evidence from such monitoring to law enforcement officials.     |
    |__________________________________________________________________|
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I presume this is because my ssh keys are located in my private home and if I run this as sudo they are not called. 
Since you cannot simple use "su" like on other Linux systems, I am at a loss how to fix this.

Let composer run without sudo doesn't work though.

Next I copied all my ssh keys to /root/.ssh , but since they are password protected I run in to the next problem:

```
$ sudo ssh-add -k
[sudo] Password for myuser: 
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: I got the whole thing now running as myuser without root. Which solves my problem, but not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ssh key for `root` and authorize access for it.

You don't really need `su` to do this. But if you really really want, you can become `root` with:

```
sudo su -
```

**Update**

So I see you copied your user's keys to `root`. So far so good.

> ```
> $ sudo ssh-add -k
> [sudo] Password for myuser: 
> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
> ```

It seems there is no authentication agent running for `root`.
You need to start one first.
Here's one way to do it:

```
# become root; will ask for user's password
sudo su -

# start ssh-agent
eval $(ssh-agent)

# add private key to agent; will ask for passphrase
ssh-add
```

After this, you can do `composer install` with `root`.

Comment: Did you start an authentication agent for `root`? Did you create keys for `root`? It seems not. It's probably best if you become `root` with `sudo su -`, and then follow the usual procedure to create and authorize keys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120082/discussion-between-janos-and-calamity-jane).

Comment: I amended my answer in light of the new information in your comments and update in your question. If you have further questions it will be easier to sort out the rest in chat, click on the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You may also add

```
Defaults        env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

to the server's sudoers file, and add -A to your ssh command line when connecting to the server. Assuming you have the correct key in your ssh agent from your local machine associated with the repository,

```
sudo composer install
```

should just work.